# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in, and a

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, fetch

I'm getting the following error :

> Warning : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in

and

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at "Insert file location here" in "Insert File
>   location here"on line

Here's my code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $con = mysql_connect("xxx.net","username","password") or die("Connection to server Failed");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("itekniks_altaroca") or die("DB Selection Failed");
        $messages_id = $_GET['id'];
        $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation where reservation_id ='$messages_id'");


        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
            $res=$row3['confirmation'];
        }
        $update1=mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET status ='out' WHERE reservation_id ='$messages_id'");
        $update2=mysql_query("UPDATE roominventory SET status ='out' WHERE confirmation = '$res'");
        header("location: home_admin.php#1");

        exit();

        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: try to var_dump($result3); whats the result?

Comment: try to remove your correct data mysql_connect("itekniks.net","itekniks_wcc","wccantipolo") this can be attack threats to your db or website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $con = mysql_connect("xxxx.net","username","password") or die("Connection to server Failed");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("xxxxdb") or die("DB Selection Failed");
        $messages_id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation where reservation_id ='$messages_id'");

        if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
            $res=$row3['confirmation'];
        }
        $update1=mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET status ='out' WHERE reservation_id ='$messages_id'");
        $update2=mysql_query("UPDATE roominventory SET status ='out' WHERE confirmation = '$res'");
        header("location: home_admin.php#1");

        exit();

        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

maybe you choose the undefined `reservation table` there. or there is `no column reservation_id`

---

add this before `mysql_fetch_array`

```
        if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }
```

---

**UPDATED my code here:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $con = mysql_connect("xxxx.net","username","password") or die("Connection to server Failed");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("xxxxdb") or die("DB Selection Failed");
        $messages_id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation where reservation_id ='$messages_id'");

        if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $confirmation = $row['confirmation'];
        $update1=mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET status ='out' WHERE reservation_id ='$messages_id'");
        $update2=mysql_query("UPDATE roominventory SET status ='out' WHERE confirmation = '$confirmation'");
        header("location: home_admin.php#1");

        exit();

        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

1. there is no column reservation_id in your reservation table

Comment: I tried that too and it is giving me the same output "Unknown column 'reservation_id' in 'where clause" Is it because there's no reservation_id in the database? Sorry for the noob question, I'm not really experienced with php :/ and Thanks for replying!

Comment: @Patrick just check this as an answer thank you Pat

Comment: checked it, and should I just add a reservation_id on the database? Thanks again.

Comment: @Patrick yeah just add it, but you should know the connection with room_id and message id that you've created there

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips! its up and running now :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you just have to print `$result3` and see what it returns.

Also, you may try:

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation where reservation_id=".$messages_id);
```